# How can I set an HTML string as the content of a Google Table Visualization cell?

Tags: google-visualization

The documentation on Google's Table Visualization has this to say:

> Table cells can be formatted using format strings, or by directly
>   inserting HTML as cell values.

That's a nice thought, but I've been working on the problem for the better part of two hours now--trying different variations of "html as cell values," and I have yet to come up with anything that doesn't get escaped.

I also haven't had any luck finding any examples of "html as cell values" in any of their documentation, but if you have a link with something good, I'll be glad to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the Table's "allowHtml" option to true, otherwise all HTML will be escaped.  The options are case sensitive, so make sure you enter is as "allowHtml" and not "allowHTML".